# Can't get this PHP code working

Tags: php

This code is always go to "index.php?err=1" and i don't know why.

'acceso_db.php' is the database connection (it is ok)

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Nick']);
        $usuario_clave = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pas']); 
        $usuario_clave = sha1($usuario_clave); //la clave se comprueba en SHA1

        // comprobamos que los datos ingresados en el formulario coincidan con los de la BD 
        include('acceso_db.php'); 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email' AND clave='$usuario_clave'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql)or die ("error en el select.");
        if (false === $result) {
            echo mysql_error();
        }
        else if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            if($_POST['recordar']){
                mt_srand (time());
                $auth = mt_rand(1000000,999999999);
                $sql="UPDATE usuarios set Auth='$auth' WHERE email='$email' AND clave='$usuario_clave'";
                $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
                setcookie("id_usuario", $email, time()+(60*60*24*365));
                setcookie("galleta", $auth, time()+(60*60*24*365));
            }
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row["email"];
            mysql_free_result($result);
            header("Location: index.php"); 
        }else {
            mysql_free_result($result); 
            header("Location: index.php?err=1"); 

        }
```

Comment: have you checked whether the query is returning any values?

Comment: just check your sql query and execute it directly in your database via phpMyAdmin. Does it work?

Comment: The query its ok in phpmyadmin. it's like mysql_fetch_array isn't working...

Comment: Don't ever store a userid in a cookie. Fill the cookie with a random string that corresponds what that session in the database. Also never use `mysql_*` as they are deprecated.

Comment: are you sure about you the value of $_POST['recordar'] in your  if($_POST['recordar']) ?

Comment: the problem isn't with $_POST['recordar'] as it is the tickbox to remember the login

Comment: Is this script running as index.php? If so then it's probably working the first time around - but when it redirects to self the POST variables are not set and it automatically repeats and fails the second time.

Comment: no, this script is in a file named "comprobar.php"

Comment: $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Nick']);
            $usuario_clave = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pas']);

generates bool(false) so, i don't really do the sql with the right parameters, how do i fix this? (while using th real scape string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have some problem with your code.. try this edit...

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Nick']);
$usuario_clave = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pas']);
$usuario_clave = sha1($usuario_clave); //la clave se comprueba en SHA1
// comprobamos que los datos ingresados en el formulario coincidan con los de la BD 
include('acceso_db.php');
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email' AND clave='$usuario_clave'");
if (!$sql)
{
    echo mysql_error();
    header("Location: index.php?err=1");
    exit;
}
else
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        if ($_POST['recordar'])
        {
            mt_srand(time());
            $auth = mt_rand(1000000, 999999999);
            $sql2 = mysql_query("UPDATE usuarios set Auth='$auth' WHERE email='$email' AND clave='$usuario_clave'");
           if(!$sql2)
           {
            echo 'update query failed';
            exit;
           }
            setcookie("id_usuario", $email, time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365));
            setcookie("galleta", $auth, time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365));
        }
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row["email"];
        mysql_free_result($sql);
        header("Location: index.php");
   } 
}
```

please let me know if you want any further guidance...

Comment: now with this, it just stays in the .php file of the login cheking, and the page is blank

Comment: put `ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); error_reporting(-1)` on the top of your code... and check which error it throws..

Comment: nothing, rigth now the page is a blank, i don't know why

Comment: The problem is this: $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Nick']); $usuario_clave = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pas']); generates bool(false) so, i don't really do the sql with the right parameters, how do i fix this? (while using th real scape string)

Comment: than try checking without `mysql_real_escape_strint()` function... remove that function temporarily

Comment: ok i got it working but when i got redirected to index.php i got a this message: Access denied for user 'root'@'x.x.x.x' (using password: NO) (I hid the ip)

Comment: its your database connection problem.. check ip, username and password again

Comment: Ok, i fixed it, the main problem was with the mysql_real_escape_string(), so i changed to MSQLI and it is a bit different of MYSQL so I had to check a lot of things, THANK YOU ALL. BTW, the rest of the code i put here was ok (not perfect)

Comment: @user3387688 he he... enjoy than.. If you liked my answer than please +1 and check correct .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ofc it does. You always redirect to this url.

```
header("Location: index.php?err=1");
```

Its fixed and will never change. The code does what it should. You should replace the `err=1` with the values you actually want to use in the GET.

Comment: if $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) its ok shouldn't it go to "index.php" ?

I'ts a login code

I made it 1 year ago and it was working...

Comment: btw don 't use mysql_* functions anymore. they are marked as deprecated and will be removed in the next major php release.

Comment: I suppose that your query returns nothing, so `$row` is empty or false. try `var_dump($row)` and check for its content.

Comment: There you go. So something is wrong with your query.

Comment: I don't know why, that query works perfect on phpmyadmin, changing $email with the email and $usuario_clave with the sha1 of the password

Comment: Maybe the mistake is before the query and the variables you use inside it are already wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if (isset($row)) { 
    if ($_POST['recordar']) {
        mt_srand(time());
        $auth = mt_rand(1000000, 999999999);
        $sql = "UPDATE usuarios set Auth='$auth' WHERE email='$email' AND clave='$usuario_clave'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        setcookie("id_usuario", $email, time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365));
        setcookie("galleta", $auth, time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365));
    }
    $_SESSION['email'] = $row["email"];
    mysql_free_result($result);
    header("Location: index.php");
} else {
    mysql_free_result($result);
    header("Location: index.php?err=1");
}
```

Comment: check whether values there in $rows using $var_dump($row);